# Missing AESNI, RDRAND and RDSEED capabilities?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, linux-kvm, libvirt

I've got a machine with a Core-i5 5200U. Its a 5th generation processor, so it has AESNI, RDRAND and RDSEED. Its the reason I bought the machine.

The machine is running Ubuntu Server 14.04.03. Ubuntu is providing KVM and libvirt. One of the guests is Debian 8.2, and Debian provides [X32 support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7635013). X32 is different than X86 and X64; also see [Debian x32 port](http://debian-x32.org/) on the Debian wiki.

When I grep ***`dmesg`*** on the Debian guest, I see the architecture is enabled:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i x32
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=69773d98-b9fa-4695-8392-92759d8e6094 ro syscall.x32=y syscall.x32=y quiet
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=69773d98-b9fa-4695-8392-92759d8e6094 ro syscall.x32=y syscall.x32=y quiet
[    0.328179] Enabled x32 syscalls
```

Two of the three native CPU features are listed in capabilities on the Ubuntu host, which is kind of surprising since I would expect to see AES before the others:

```
$ virsh capabilities | egrep "(aes|rdrand|rdseed)"
      <feature name='rdseed'/>
      <feature name='rdrand'/>
```

However, when I cat ***`/proc/cpuinfo`*** under the Debian guest, its missing the three CPU features I want to test under X32:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 6
model name  : QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.0.0
...
flags       : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx
              fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good nopl pni vmx cx16 x2apic popcnt
              hypervisor lahf_lm abm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept
...
```

I've reviewed [Libvirt identifies host processor as a different model from the hardware documentation](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Libvirt_identifies_host_processor_as_a_different_model_from_the_hardware_documentation), but its not clear to me what I should do to enable the instructions I am trying to test under the architecture.

How can I enable AESNI, RDRAND and RDSEED on the CPU in the Debian VM?

---

Here is the script I used to create the VM:

```
$ cat mk-vm.sh
#!/bin/bash

NAME=Debian_8_x64
ISO_PATH=/opt/libvirt/images/debian-8.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso
DISK_PATH="/opt/libvirt/machines/$NAME/$NAME.img"

mkdir -p "/opt/libvirt/machines/$NAME"

virt-install \
  --connect qemu:///system \
  --virt-type kvm \
  --name "$NAME" \
  --ram 2048 \
  --disk path=$DISK_PATH,size=8 \
  --vnc \
  --cdrom $ISO_PATH \
  --livecd \
  --network network=host-bridge \
  --os-type linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the CPU "model" that libvirt/qemu uses for the VM.

The simplest way is to use the "host" model, that will expose all libvirt/qemu supported flags from the host to the VM.

In libvirt XML stanza:

```
<cpu mode='host-model'/>
```

Full doc' here: https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsCPU